# if else condition is not working with checked and unchecked

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery code when I click on second td which has an input in a tr then is this input is checked in my code  if statement not execute it execute else statement similarly else statement also execute give a solution to this.

```
$(function(){
    $("table.confirmit-grid >tbody  >tr >td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",true);
    $("table.confirmit-grid >tbody  >tr >td:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
        if($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) // this statement execute when input is unchecked
        {
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else //this statement execute when input is checked
        {
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",true);
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @ Ehsan Sajjad I use web application and if we use this code on firebug it works great but when I put it into web then this is not working

Comment: without html no one can figure out what's happening

Comment: Please try to rephrase your "question" (you don't actually even seem to be asking a question) while making use of proper punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is backwards:

```
// this will be true if there are any checked boxes, so you need to negate it with a !
if($(this).find("input").is(":checked"))
```

I think you want

```
$(function(){
    $("table.confirmit-grid >tbody  >tr >td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",true);
    $("table.confirmit-grid >tbody  >tr >td:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).find("input").is(":checked")) // this statement execute when input is unchecked
        {
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else //this statement execute when input is checked
        {
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("disabled",true);
            $(this).parent().find("td:nth-child(3) input").prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
});
```

// this will be true if there are any checked boxes

Comment: Like Patrick stated above - you don't have a question. Please describe  clearly what you intend to see as the result and what you are observing. Perhaps create a http://jsfiddle.com of the issue as well.

Comment: I updated the answer with data that has labels and values and used the label to generate the text. I also added a jsfiddle example.

Comment: I get the fix solution for this we should use .live('click',function(){ }); it work great